# Disable inline stylesheets and separate them in files using webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-3, vue-loader

Is there a config option in Vue to make a separate CSS file?

I tried using the webpack plugin to extract CSS. However, Vue still loads the same styles inline.

Is there something I’m missing about Vue? Or is this purely my misunderstanding of webpack?

[webpack.config.js](https://gist.github.com/dfector/cf25940b1804600d03b842d2e37d03ea)

Comment: Post your webpack config too so we can see what you have done, and what is missing

Comment: Added link to webpack.config.js